# Why the aluminum ball first jumps, then hovers with two coaxial AC solenoidal magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, everyday-life

Once in a while google suggest an intriguing video: [Professor Eric Laithwaite: The Circle of Magnetism - 1968](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tJfqMYHaQw)

There is AC 50Hz driving two concentric, very short solenoids, the outer is longer than the inner such that the even larger aluminum spherical shell fits in to the end.

Turning on the power suddenly (one coil or both) causes the sphere to jump almost a meter.

With the outer coil, the coil floats (stable against gravity) but is unstable in the radial direction. But with both coils powered with "a phase offset" between then (which I am not sure I understand why it makes the hand tool rotate) the transverse motion is also stable oscillations about equilibrium as well.

[Eddy current repulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current#Repulsive_effects_and_levitation) is fairly easy to demonstrate and discussed in most E&M  tomes, but I've never encountered this particular kind of levitation.

I can not figure out how any of these particular things happen, is there a *relatively simple way* to explain the basics of what is happening:

1. why the sudden jump so high at power-up
2. why the hand tool rotates when there is a phase difference between the two coils
3. why the transverse motion is stable with both coils powered

---

[image: Professor Eric Laithwaite: The Circle of Magnetism - 1968]

[image: Professor Eric Laithwaite: The Circle of Magnetism - 1968]

[image: Professor Eric Laithwaite: The Circle of Magnetism - 1968]

[image: Professor Eric Laithwaite: The Circle of Magnetism - 1968]